# Wordpress sidebar not floating in Opera

Tags: css, wordpress, opera

[This site](http://brinkley.doig.com.au/) displays fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8, but **in Opera, the sidebar, is pushed below the content**, and does not fit properly.

Can you see why Opera behaves differently to the rest?

The site uses a child theme of TwentyTwelve, and the sidebar div has id "secondary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS sets the width in `em` at http://brinkley.doig.com.au/wp-content/themes/brinkley/style.css?ver=3.4.2 line #1342 (inside media query):

```
.site {
 max-width: 68.571428571rem;;
}
```

... just change em to pixels: `max-width: 960px;` because Opera calculated it to 959 pixels.
The content is not responsive enough, you have other issues for smaller width.

Comment: Thanks skobaljic.  Do you have a tutorial on how to make images responsive?  Do I use % for width?

Comment: If you target older browsers that do not support CSS3, than your images must be inline and all widths should be in percent, together for columns and for `<img>` tags, the image height should be default `height: auto;`. If you target for instance IE9+, than you can use background images, but you need to control `background-size` property - take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp and/or google it.